# construct predefined messages with properties to post on Facebook android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to post a pre-defined message on Facebook through my android application. I got everything to work except the 'properties' field. I want to post a message where it says:
More information: here
and when the user clicks on 'here', it should link to the page.

This is what I did:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
 String s2 = "{'More information':{'text':'here', 'href':" + details + "}}";
 params.putString("properties", s2);
```

where 'details' is the link to the page.

But it seems like facebook is not picking up this line. I successfully set up the caption, picture and other fields.

Any insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, as far as I know, we do not support HTML in status updates.  We will automatically create a link if you post a valid URL however, so I would suggest just pasting out the full link

> ".....More information: (www.yourURLhere.com)"

On Facebook, www.yourURLhere.com will be a clickable link.